# In Legends, was there ever a third Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-legends, weapon, death-star

Of course, there are a lot of similarities and echos between *The Force Awakens* and previous (movie) canon.

[What are the things that “The Force Awakens” borrowed/parallel from “A New Hope?”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111224/what-are-the-things-that-the-force-awakens-borrowed-parallel-from-a-new-hope)

In particular,

> there is the Starkiller Base, which is essentially a third amped-up Death Star.
>  (Related: [Why does The Dark Side keep building Death Stars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112753/why-does-the-dark-side-keep-building-death-stars))

## Was there ever a third planet killer in Legends?

Comment: I hope they would've learned better after the first one (;

Comment: In fact, there were so many over-powered planet killers in Legends/EU that I'm sure I've read something scathing by Timothy Zahn on the subject... but can I find it to reference, of course not.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### There were *many* planetkillers in Legends -- even [a third Death Star!](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Star_III)

The Deathstar III was a "fake" built by the warlord [Ennix Devian](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ennix_Devian) , but it had a superlaser and a trench with heavier guards than the original Death Star. This is the Death Star that gets destroyed in Star Tours.
If it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, and can destroy planets like a duck...

[image: DS3]

Then, of course, there was the Death Star Prototype, which was illogically built at the same time as the production model.

[image: DSP]

As for the other planet killers in Legends...

The [Mass Shadow Generator](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mass_Shadow_Generator) could destroy all life on a planet, ground all ships in orbit, and destroy the planet itself.

[image: MSG]

[Centerpoint Station](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Centerpoint_Station) could tear planets apart with its hyperspace-driven tractor beam.

[image: CPS]

[Yo'gand's Core](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yo%27gand%27s_Core) was a biomechanical meteor made through Yuuzhan Vong manipulation of moons and an alien species that could manipulate gravitational fields.

[image: YGC]

A [Dark Reaper](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Reaper) could siphon out the power of Force sensitives and use it to create a turbolaser blast.

[image: DR]

The [Sun Crusher](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sun_Crusher) could make a star go supernova, destroying all the planets in its system.

[image: SC]
<sub>(source: [nocookie.net](https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/8/8e/Sun_Crusher-NEGWT.jpg))</sub>

The [Galaxy Gun](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy_Gun) was essentially a floating planet destroying gun.

[image: GG]
<sub>(source: [nocookie.net](https://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/6/65/Galaxygun_negwt.jpg))</sub>

The [World Devastators](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/World_Devastator) would use tractor beams to tear a planet apart, while keeping its resources usable.

[image: WD]
<sub>(source: [nocookie.net](https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/b/b5/WD_NEGWT.jpg))</sub>

And these are just a select few. The list goes on!

Comment: Since they're asking about a Death Star, maybe add a description/summary of this DS-3 you mention.

Comment: "If it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, and can destroy planets like a duck..."...then we're gonna need ta git us a bigger gol-durned SHOTGUN, that's what I'm a-thinkin'!!!!!!! :-)

Comment: DarkSaber - built by a Hutt crimelord, it was essentially the laser component of the Death Star without the accommodation and barracks.

Comment: Also related, the [Darksaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darksaber) battlestation

Comment: @Thunderforge Except he specifically asked about other "planet killers". Regardless, I'll add it.

Comment: I suppose I was looking more at the title than the question itself. Thanks for adding it.

Answer (score 3):

While there is a [DS-1](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/DS-1_Orbital_Battle_Station) (Death Star 1) and [DS-2](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/DS-2_Orbital_Battle_Station) (Death Star 2), there is no DS-3 listed on Wookieepedia.

[Axelrod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115394/1148) makes mention of a third Death Star. However it is stated:

> A **fake** Death Star III was built by the warlord Ennix Devian of the Galactic Empire - (emphasis added) http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_III

That is was fake, although it did appear to have defenses.

There was the original [Death Star Prototype](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_prototype), which was located in a black hole cluster called the "Maw Installation." While technically the first Death Star, it was the third one introduced to the principal heroes of Star Wars.

It made a first appearance in the Legends book "Jedi Search," book one of *The Jedi Academy Trilogy.*

Also introduced in that series was the super weapon [Sun Crusher](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sun_Crusher)

> The Sun Crusher was a nearly indestructible craft that was no larger than a starfighter, but was capable of unleashing destruction on a magnitude that dwarfed even the Death Star's capabilities. Unlike the Death Star, which destroyed individual planets, the Sun Crusher could destroy an entire star system by causing its target star to turn into a supernova

Comment: There *is* a Death Star III on Wookiepedia.

Comment: @Axelrod I saw your answer and attributed it to you in mine. However, they say it is a fake, and I believe them.

Comment: If it looks like a death star, orbits like a death star, and has a superlaser like a death star... :D

Comment: ... it's a duck! Or maybe a witch? If it weighs as much?...

Comment: @MattGutting - I built the first death star and it sank into the swamp...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previously-mentioned examples, there was also "[The Tarkin"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(superweapon)):

> The Tarkin, or the Tarkin Project, was an Imperial superweapon modeled in principle after the first Death Star battlestation and named in honor of the late Grand Moff Wilhuff Tarkin. The Tarkin combined the first Death Star's offensive capabilities in the form of a planet-destroying ionic cannon superlaser with a defensive shield generator and a set of engines. Imperial engineer Bevel Lemelisk designed the Tarkin, at the behest of Emperor Palpatine following the Death Star's destruction at the Battle of Yavin, as a prototype weapons testbed for the construction of the Eclipse-class Super Star Destroyer, a massive warship armed with a ship-mounted superlaser. With technological refinements, the Tarkin improved upon the mistakes learned from the first Death Star, including the absence of the single design flaw—an exposed thermal exhaust port—that proved to be the original battlestation's undoing, in the name of the development of a second Death Star, built concurrently with the Tarkin.

[image: The Tarkin]

It wasn't exactly a Death Star, but it was a "third planet killer" with some of the same parts.

Comment: Ahem - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134975/how-did-chewbacca-get-c-3pos-parts-back-after-being-captured

Comment: @Valorum Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Dark Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Empire) comic series, the [Eclipse-class Star Destroyer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eclipse_(Eclipse-class)) had a planet-destroying super-laser based on the Death Star design built into it.